# Change the Effect of Button once it is clicked WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to apply the following changes when the `Button` is pressed.

```
<Button>
    <Button.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="5"/>
    </Button.Effect>
</Button>
```

Comment: You might want to look into how templates work. Those will allow you to do exactly that with zero code.

Comment: Use a `Style` and `Trigger` to handle those things for your button.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about handling the `Click` event for the `Button`?

```
<Button Content="Click me!" Click="Button_Click_1" Margin="10" />
```

---

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    button.Effect = new System.Windows.Media.Effects.DropShadowEffect()
    {
        BlurRadius = 10,
        ShadowDepth = 5
    };
}
```

Or use a `Style` that binds to the `IsPressed` property if you want to display the shadow only while the Button is being pressed:

```
<Button Content="Button">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="5"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Or use a `ToggleButton` and set the `Effect` property based on its `IsChecked` property:

```
<ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="5"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```