# WPF - OuterGlow Effect when button is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a button in WPF and when the button is pressed, it shall generate an outerglow effect. However the effect takes place when the button is not pressed, how would I make the effect take place only when button is pressed?

Here is my XAML:

```
    <Button.Effect>
    <DropShadowEffect
   BlurRadius="20" ShadowDepth="0" Color="DarkBlue">
    </DropShadowEffect>
</Button.Effect>


</Button>
```

This is my edited code:

```
 <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="147,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" PreviewMouseDown="button_PreviewMouseDown">

            <Style x:Name="Triggers" TargetType ="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Button.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect
           BlurRadius="20" ShadowDepth="0" Color="DarkBlue">
                            </DropShadowEffect>
                        </Button.Effect>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>


        </Button>
```

Can anyone tell me why it's not working?

Edited:

```
<menu:HomeButton x:Name="BtnHome" PreviewMouseDown="BtnHome_PreviewMouseDown" TouchDown="BtnHome_TouchDown"   >
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Effect">
                                    <Setter.Value>

                                        <DropShadowEffect
       BlurRadius="20" ShadowDepth="0" Color="DarkBlue"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>


                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </menu:HomeButton>
```

Comment: Do you want it to change for the duration of the press, or do you want it to hold a state on/off ?

Comment: From the snippet I believe you have directly added the effect, which implies it will always have the effect.You have added this code in the Triggers, e.g EventTrigger. Check out the sample http://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_triggers.htm

Comment: I only want the effect to take place when the button is pressed. I tried adding the <Trigger> property but it's not working

Comment: Why isn't my code(edited) working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Style` property and a trigger for `IsPressed`:

```
<Button Content="Button">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" ShadowDepth="0" Color="DarkBlue"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Reference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/46279626/6741868

Comment: Can you look at my edited code: it's the same but doesn't work

Comment: Well, the only difference I can think of is `true` changing to `True`, could you try that to see if it works. If not, is there an error or it just doesn't show the shadow when pressed?

Comment: The style element should go inside <Button.Style> and not direct a child, as per CookiMonster and the Value inside the <Setter.Value> as shown by Keyur Patel

Comment: Well caught @AsitK, `<Button.Style>` and `</Button.Style>` are missing.

Comment: But the documentation property is in MSDN , that's weird

Comment: So when the button is pressed, effects comes in. How would I make the effect appear once when clicked and then dissapear? So when i clicked again, effect comes in

Comment: I have been doing WPF for a pretty long time now, use Keyur Patel's code as it is

Comment: Try the animation shown in Event Trigger as in the page http://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_triggers.htm

Comment: To achieve my answer?

Comment: @CookieMonster I'm not sure what your requirement is. When I test my code with a button it activates the shadow when clicked, and disappears when I finish the click, as expected. Could you explain what you're requirements are?

Comment: My requirement is as what you just described. However, when i click the button, it activates the shadow and stays there, i want to make it dissapear after i click.

Comment: Oh okay, please disregard my message, I forgot I had my code behind also trigger the same event but with MouseDown only.

Comment: How would I do the same thing in code behind instead of XAML? I use PreviousMouseDown event to fire the shadow but what do I need to do to make sure it behaves like the XAML you provided?

Comment: If you use the `PreviewMouseDown` event to trigger the shadow, you can simply use another event, `PreviewMouseUp` and deactivate it.

Comment: That's what i thought

Comment: Can you look at my edited code? I tried using this on another XAML, doesn't see to be working.

Comment: I'll reply on your new question.